# correctly escape loop after it's correctly matched html parse

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

I'm comparing hash values of a html page to detect new activity, I've set up a trigger and it's working well but I have trouble escaping the loop once it detects new activity and it isn't the trigger.

I was told this was a simple issue but I'm unfamiliar with loops.

So I have

```py
if myhash == myhash2:  # match hashes to detect site change
  print('[-]No Change Detected on ' + str(url2) + "")
  time.sleep(4)

if myhash != myhash2:
  status_string = '[!]New hash',""
```

Comparing site states by hash value

```py
mysplitpokemon = (target_element.text.split("!pokemon", 1)[1])
```

Matching my trigger word and retrieving the word after it.

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.qwerty.com")
```

Carry on doing something with the values..

I believe i'm looping it wrong from now on, I need it to escape the nested loop of retreiving `mysplitpokemon`and go back to `if myhash == myhash2` but retain the value of `mysplitpokemon` until the next main loop run. But instead webdriver just opens up infinite instances and it fails to match the the text after `!pokemon`

so my loop is

```py
while True:
  # first page request
  while 1:
    # second request to the same page
    try:
      # match the hashes
      if myhash == myhash2:
        something()
      if myhash != myhash2:
        continue
      while True:
        parseFunction()
        postFunction()
        break
```

Comment: I see no loops in your code. Please make updates

Comment: Your indentation in the code containing the loops seems off (i.e. there is no indention after the `try` statement). In addition it should be `continue` instead of `continue()`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried to fix your indentation issues to my best guess please revise those changes. In its current state though the `try` statement doesn't serve any purpose. Also for me at least it's not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish. Try to elaborate on this. What do you consider the "main loop" and "nested loop" - there are three nested loops and four loops in total. In which loop are you "retrieving `mysplitpokemon`"? This is currently not clear because you omitted it in your final code exhibit.

Comment: Sorry but I paid a guy to solve it, and it too him a while so granted it wasn't an easy problem.

He went about and wrote the hash values into a file, and then read the file, something which I could have done myself but i'm trying to avoid redundant coding.

tl;dr problem solved thanks for the ffort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                else:
                pass
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            driver.quit()
            pass
```

Escape the loop twice while handling errors correctly.